# conflicting font-size being put on menu bar when it only needs to be in the div content

Tags: css

i have a menu bar on my page that has buttons you click to open other divs,
in those divs i have content which i change color and font-size, the problem i am having is its not only changing the font-size to the content in the div, its also changing the font size on the menu bar.. but when i change the color it only changes the color to the content in the div, and not the menu bar. i am kind of stuck and confused at this point.. any help i would appreciate it, thanks, what i would like to do is only change the font-size to the content in the div without it conflicting with the menu bar and changing the size to the words on the menu bar

css

```
#profile_about_me_friends {
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  color:#000000;
  font-family:"Baskerville Old Face",serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size:20px; <-- this is conflicting with all the text on the menu bar <--
  background-color:rgba(0,0,255);
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  right:-1200px;
  padding:40px;
  transition:left 0 ease-in-out;
```

Comment: who downvoted my question for no reason ?

Comment: thats not even cool...

Comment: I assume that's because a jsfiddle link would be welcome. Also, there's a lot of code. It would be appreciated if you pinpointed the issue by making the code smaller so we don't have to spend too much time trying to understand what your code does.

Comment: And there's no HTML. Are we supposed to guess what your HTML looks like?

Comment: i posted on the code where i was having the issue at.. last time i asked a question someone got pizzy because i didn't have enough code so which one is it ? too much too less ? i can't use jsfiddle because you can't open the divs from the menu bar on jsfiddle so that would be useless

Comment: ok there is the html,, i don't see how the html would have anything to do with a conflicting size on the menu bar ..

Comment: its called a question.. do you need me to give you the answer also ? i either give to much of a code or not enough .. then its an html which doesn't have anything to do with the code. then you guys down vote A QUESTION<<< i rephrase , A QUESTION.. isn't there no wrong question.. if i knew an answer and exactly my issue i was having i wouldn't need to ask the question.. i just know its in this code here where its conflicting , its adding the font-size to both the div content and the menu bar content.. don't understand it because the menu bar content has its own size on each button

Comment: Hum... you will not get an ANSWER with that attitude. Just saying... Anyway, when you ask a question, make sure that people will understand your issue fast. We don't want to waste time decyphering your code. And we need all the **useful** data. And, honestly, I don't understand your question, and I cannot debug that kind of code without seeing it run.

Comment: _“i either give to much of a code or not enough”_ – both is bad, although too much would not be as bad as too little. Saying the HTML has nothing to do with it is just utter nonsense – the CSS is _applied_ to your HTML, and without it, seeing only your CSS tells us very little … It is _your job_ as the person asking a question to present a minimal example that makes the problem reproducible. If you can’t be bothered to create one … well then don’t expect to get your question answered, but only downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: (I've rolled back your edit to replace the question with an answer - we like to maintain questions as they were asked here. If you would like to add an answer, please do so in the answer space below. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#right_menu
 position:fixed;
 font-size:15px;  < issue is here <<<
 top:0;
 right:0;
 background-color: #FF00FF;
 width:50px;
 height:100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your frustration. I have some tips for the future. Some people like seeing more code because there's a possibility that the problem is widespread. If you have an idea of where the problem might be, you can always add a more detailed code example and then a smaller, more pinpointed example with your thoughts.

Another helpful solution is a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net). This service lets you run your code, so people can see what you're seeing, and pinpoint the problem faster.

In relation to your question, I'm glad you found a solution to the issue. Often times, it's simple mistakes that cause big problems. You may want to consider adding a font-size statement in the body, so that if you don't have a font-size stated, the element will still appear the right size. For example:

```
body {
    font-size: 15px; /* This will carry over to any elements listed under body */
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>The size carries over to p, even though it's not explicitly stated.</p>
</body>
```

Another good practice that I use now, is to use rem instead of pixels. This makes your font size more flexible. You can use rem to dynamically change the size of fonts for mobile screens. More reading available here:

- http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem
- https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/

Comment: unless you make that div have its own size ?

Comment: that was my issue lol, it was reading the body size and taking that in the menu location because i didn't have a size set in the menu also .. appreciate the feed back

Comment: Yep so if you have a font size in the body, and then another one in the div, the div's font size will take over.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, yup CSS can sometimes be tricky if you're not super careful with what class/id has what properties.

Comment: Anyway, glad to have helped out.

Comment: i lost 20 reputation from people giving negative feedback on my question.. lol oh well i can't vote up on your comment but i did check it for you

Comment: Appreciate it, and don't worry, you'll get better at asking question here. It's a tricky process, and I've lost plenty of reputation doing so as well!

Comment: But, this is a useful site, and I hope you will keep using it.

Answer (score -1):

```
body {font-size: 15px;}
```

or

```
#right_menu {position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; width: 50px; height:100%; font-size: 15px !important; background-color: #FF00FF;}
```

I don't think your css is the problem, but try option two.
If this doesn't work option one will change all text to that size.

The problem is in your html if we could see that then i could fix it.